# How to remove forward slash (\) from a string in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to remove all the backslashes from a string in my code, however when I tried the following:

```py
a = 'dfdfd\dafdfd'

print(a)

a.replace('\',' ')
```

... I encountered the following error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a.replace('\',' ')
```

Can someone explain why this is happening, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can this way(One more way to do):

```
a = 'dfdfd\dafdfd'
exclude = '\\'
s = ''.join(ch for ch in a if ch not in exclude)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use raw `r''` string -

```
a.replace(r'\',' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslash (`\`) character is an escape character. When you wrote

```py
a.replace('\',' ')
```

... Python interpreted the `\'` as a `'` inside the string, and therefore threw an error since the parser messed up. Therefore, you need to fix this by escaping the backslash character with another backslash, like so:

```py
a.replace('\\',' ')
```